# Deleting a Google App Engine alias app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently migrated an App Engine app from the master/slave datastore to the high replication datastore. This created two apps (using sample app names):

```
myapp
myapp-hd
```

And myapp.appspot.com aliases to myapp-hd.appspot.com. My question is, is it now safe to delete the original myapp application? And if I delete the myapp application, will the alias continue working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the old app ID, and the alias will continue to work. Before deleting it, though, make sure you will *never* want it again, as that app ID will be gone forever.

Comment: If I reuse that app ID, can it be set to use a high replication datastore, or is it always destined to use master/slave?

Comment: It will always be using Master/Slave. You most likely will not want to reuse the app, in any capacity, but I wanted to make sure you knew it would be gone for good.

Comment: I suggest you to don't delete the app, if you have something on the blobstore all the serving url will be deleted

Comment: The bummer is that the app counts against your 10 app limit. It would be nice if migrated apps didn't count against this limit.

Comment: @monsur: If the old application is disabled it will not count against your free app quota.

Comment: @DanHolevoet Ah i see. And I assume that this answer stays the same if the app is disabled rather than deleted?

Comment: @monsur: Yes, without the permanence of deletion. If you find you need the app again, you can re-enable it in the same place in the console.

Comment: To clarify, a "disabled" app will still cost you money (storage costs etc): "Warning: Disabling your application does not automatically cancel billing. If you disable your app but do not cancel billing, your app will continue to incur billing costs even though it is disabled."