# How to cleanup apps after GAE HRD migration

Tags: google-app-engine, migration

I have a number of applications to migrate from GAE master/slave to GAE HRD.

After migration, I have the "old" and "new" GAE apps, similar to:

foo.appspot.com (master/slave)
foo-hrd.appspot.com (HRD)

I use the console so that requests to foo.appspot.com get magically redirected to foo-hrd.appspot.com

Can anyone verify that following all this it is *safe* to delete foo.appspot.com using the GAE console. Specifically that I can delete my old app after the migration, but the old URL foo.appspot.com wont "go away" when I delete my old app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to have been answered in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941558/deleting-a-google-app-engine-alias-app

Answer (score 0):

The URL can never be re-used if that is your concern: "Once your application is actually deleted, however, you cannot recover its state or data. Only its application ID remains (and this can never be re-used)."

Additionally, it takes 72 hours of a disabled application before you can permanently delete it - giving you plenty of time to identify any unintended consequences.

More information here, though I'm sure you have already checked this out?:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings#Disable_or_Delete_Your_Application

Comment: I've read to documentation. It really doesn't mention my concern unles ive missed something. My concern isn't about whether the URL would be reused. I'm really looking for confirmation that the forwarding will continue to function after the deletion. Who knows t might stop working after the 72 hour period. Or may be 1 month later.. I'm just trying to get confirmation of what behavior is to be expected. Can anyone from google answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration) - specifically:

*"Important: As the last step, you will make your old application ID an "alias" for the new one; thus, if users browse your application at old-name.appspot.com, they will instead see your new application (which you might think of as new-name.appspot.com). You do not need to point your users or update your documentation to a new URL after you migrate. You do not incur any billing costs when you do this migration."*

I infer from this that you can safely delete your old files. Regarding your old URL - it would appear that you can delete that, so long as you've properly set up the new URL.  Here's a [discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/cJhiIbeq-zU) about the latter issue that you might find helpful.

Comment: Hi Lynn .. I am really looking for a more specific answer than "infer". Has any one got experience in doing this and can confirm the behavior? Any one from @google.com app engine team who can comment?